# How to get button to inherit color

Tags: html, css

Color inheritance doesn't seem to work for button.

```
<div style='color:blue'>
    <button>
        hi
    </button>
</div>
```

When I debug the above code, I see that the button inherits the color "blue" from div. However, it is still rendered as black.

If I set the button's color to blue directly, it renders blue as expected.

How do I get color inheritance to work for button?

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vivmaha/jwfb77xj/2/).

Comment: `button { color: inherit; }` or `button { color: currentColor; }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/jwfb77xj/3/)

You can add `color:inherit` to the `button`. Thus add this to your css as below..

**CSS**

```
button{
    color: inherit;
}
```

As in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/inherit)

> The inherit CSS-value causes the element for which it is specified to
>   take the computed value of the property from its parent element. It is
>   allowed on every CSS property.

Comment: This fixed it. I didn't even try it since the browser debugger said the color was automatically being inherited...

Answer (score 0):

The default button behavior does not inherit, that is why buttons are rendered in the default look except directly styled

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).